# Type of a tuple-PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, types, tuples

If I have a single element in a tuple it returns type of that element instead of tuple. Why does this happens?

If I check the type of this variable t1 , this will return integer type instead of tuple. Why does it give me this result?
t1 = (1)
print(type(t1))
Output: int

If I get multiple elements in that tuple it works fine and returns type as tuple. Can someone please explain this concept?

t1=(1,2,3)
print(type(t1))
Output: tuple

Comment: That is not a single element in a tuple. A tuple with a single element would be `(1,)`, not `(1)`.

Comment: The comma is making a tuple, not the parentheses. `t = 1, 2` is a tuple.